# How can I stamp a texture on top of a material?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have a material that covers my model in camouflage. Now I want to stamp a regular old UV texture on top of that material, in such a way that transparencies in the texture show the material. Say I want to stamp a large letter "A" on top of the camo; the A only takes up the corner of the face, and the material should still how through the middle gap of the A.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhOPvj1DbVQ here is a tutorial on how to add decals to models

Comment: Thanks @NascentSpace, the comments on that video led me to this one which is much easier and works perfectly for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGxMY2lMoLw